# Varying number of buttons used on XCode storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am just getting into iOS development and am building a simple quiz app. The number of responses for each question varies. For example the first question is True/False with two button responses while the second question has four possible answers.

The way that I am building this as of now is having a set of two buttons and another set of four buttons and I am hiding the set of buttons that is not supposed to be on the screen at a given time.

I feel like there's a simpler way of doing this but do not know how. What if I have 10 different possible number of answers? Do I have to have 10 sets of buttons that I turn on and off depending on the question?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Just use tableView, each quiz is in a section.

Comment: Not *everything* has to be represented on the storyboard. You can have views that you add/remove programmatically from a container view (like `UICollectionView`, `UIStackView` or just `UIView`, for example).

Comment: Do whatever you can, first.  Make changes when you realize you can do the job in a better approach.  So what's the point of your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to approach this.

If your buttons will all fit in one row or one column, a vertical or horizontal stack view (`UIStackView`) works really well. You put the buttons in a stack view, and just hide the ones you don't need. The stack view adjusts the spacing and positioning of the remaining items automatically. You can also add and remove items into a stack view at runtime, but your application might not need that.

You could also use 2 horizontal stack views on top of each other and add a little control logic that decides which buttons to show and hide so they look visually pleasing.

There are also views called `UITableView`s that will create a vertical scrolling list of items of arbitrary length. Those are a little harder to program.

Table views have a "sectioned" mode where the items are grouped into sections. A sectioned table view with a section for each question and its answers would work quite well.

There there is the `UICollectionView` class, which can do everything a table view can do and more. They can handle lists like table views can, grids of items, plus custom layouts like carousels, but require a little more work to program.